# Probability Question using Urns & Colored Balls

Tags: probability

You have one urn with 3 yellow balls, 2 red balls, and 6 blue balls.  You draw without replacement 3 balls, and none are yellow.  What is the probability of the sample?

Comment: What is your thinking at this point?

Comment: Do this step by step: What is the probability of the first ball not being yellow?

Comment: you need to show us some effort ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to @Bram28, find the initial probabilities of each color. i.e) yellow = 3/11, red = 2/11 and blue = 6/11. And since there is not replacement, these probabilities will change.

So the probability that the first color is $NOT$ yellow is 8/11,

Now what if this happens 3 times in a row?? Can you figure that out..

$$\frac{8}{11}*\frac{7}{10}*\frac{6}{9}$$
= .339 or 33.9%

Comment: The OP stated *without* replacement ...

Comment: So then I don't use a negation rule to rule out the yellow balls?

Comment: I did use the negation rule, because 3/11 are yellow so 1 - (3/11) is 8/11, all the possible balls that are not yellow.. And then this changes because you're not replacing the balls. And you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in this problem you are being asked for the probability that in your sample there is no yellow balls. From the problem, you know that there are 3 yellow balls, and 8 non-yellow balls (2 red + 6 blue). So the probability of selecting a non-yellow ball is $8/11$, as there are 11 balls total.

Now what about if we select one more? Well since we pulled one out our total number of balls is now 10, and non-yellow balls is now 7. Can you take it from there?

Comment: there actually is replacement, so total of 11 every time

Comment: @Brandon, in the problem s/he states "you draw without replacement..."

Comment: Yes youre right. I read it wrong. no need to down vote lol, its an easy fix

Comment: Ill actually upvote this because you provide insightful information, without explicitly giving the answer. Maybe that's why I got a downvote. Cheers